# Terminating thread thats waiting in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to learn how to use threading with networking and need to stop a thread if a connection is closed. I have a list of multiple connections and a thread that checks if they are still open.

If a connection has closed i need to terminate the GetData() thread but i don't know how to do that without checking for an exit event every loop. The problem is that the GetData() thread doesn't loop but sits at line 25 and waits for a response. If the connection has closed it never gets a response and just keeps sitting there until i kill the program.

How do i kill a thread outside of the thread. I understand that this is not easily done with threading but is there maybe some other library that allows this? I also tried using multiprocessing instead but i couldn't get it to work so i just gave up on that.

```
from threading import Thread
import socket

def MakeSocket():
    try:
        global MainSocket
        MainSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
        print ("Socket successfully created") 
    except socket.error as err:  
        print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err)) 
    MainSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    MainSocket.bind(('', 1337))
    MainSocket.listen(5)

    global c
    global addr
    c, addr = MainSocket.accept()
    Thread(target=GetData, args=()).start()
    Thread(target=CheckIfOpen, args=()).start()

def GetData():
    while True:
        try:
            #Try to recieve data from connection.
            RecievedData = c.recv(4096).decode()
            print(RecievedData)
        except:
            print ("\nError: GetData failed.\n")
            return

def CheckIfOpen():
    while True:
        #wait 5 sec between each test
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            #try to send data "test".
            c.send("test".encode())
        except:
            #if it fails then the connection has been closed. Close the GetData thread
            #Don't know how to close the GetData thread

MakeSocket()
```

I know this looks silly but it isn't all my code. I just changed it a bit and included the important parts. It still contains the same problem. I don't have all those global variables in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was wrong.
https://reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/kx925z/terminating_thread_thats_waiting/

u/oefd pointed something i missed out in the comments.